# Count number of results per CustomerID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking into phone calls to customers and I need a column that count the results for previous calls to the same customer.

E.g how many of the prior calls has ended with the result "No Contact"

I have been looking into the `CASE WHEN` function and the `LAG` function, but  I haven't been able get the result I am looking for

The below and example of what I am trying to achieve (the PriorNotInterested column):

[image: example table]

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.) Take a look at [mcve] before you start.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL server.

Comment: and did try to upload as formatted text, but the table didn't turn out very pretty in the editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a conditional window `sum()` between the first record of the client and the record preceeding the current one. Most RDBMS support the `rows between` clause in window functions:

```
select 
    t.*,
    sum(case when Result = 'Not Interested' then 1 else 0 end)
        over (
            partition by customer_id 
            order by Call_date
            rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
        ) CountNotIntererstedPrior
from mytable t
```

Comment: Thanks GMB - this is exactly what I was looking for and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of GMB's answer, but it doesn't return `NULL` if the first call is "not interested":

```
select t.*,
       (sum(v.not_interested) over (partition by t.customer_id order by t.call_date) -
        not_interested
       ) as countnotinterestedprior
from t cross apply
     (values (case when result = 'Not Interested' then 1 else 0 end)
     ) v(not_interested);
```

Comment: Thanks for adding that. It makes a lot of sense in my case to get rid of the NULL values.